# Error on ibm filemonitoring while websphere starts up

Tags: java, websphere

Has anyone encountered this error? Where does it come from and can I do something about it?

This error came right after the attempt to deploy the application.

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKE0701E: [com.ibm.ws.kernel.filemonitor.internal.scan.ScanningCoreServiceImpl(24)] The setMonitor method has thrown an exception Bundle:com.ibm.ws.kernel.filemonitor(id=17) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.ibm.ws.artifact.overlay.internal.DirectoryBasedOverlayContainerImpl.setOverlayDirectory(DirectoryBasedOverlayContainerImpl.java:1188)
    at [internal classes]
```

Comment: Ok that's weird, i have removed the application tag from the server.xml and now the error is gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's really strange. It's likely that the workarea cache for the application has been corrupted somehow. You should be able to solve the problem by starting the server with the '--clean' option or just deleting the workarea directory and restarting the server.

The code in question is in open liberty here: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/integration/dev/com.ibm.ws.artifact.overlay/src/com/ibm/ws/artifact/overlay/internal/DirectoryBasedOverlayContainerImpl.java

It's performing various checks on the cache directory (something like workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/xx/data/cacheAdapt/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_yy) to make sure everything is sane.